# Multiplying the value within two "Maybe" monads?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm currently in the process of trying to learn Haskell, and ran into an odd issue regarding the `Maybe` monad which I can't seem to figure out.

As an experiment, I'm currently trying to take a string, convert each letter to an arbitrary number, and multiply/combine them together. Here's what I have so far:

```
lookupTable :: [(Char, Int)]
lookupTable = [('A', 1), ('B', 4), ('C', -6)]

strToInts :: String -> [Maybe Int]
strToInts = map lookupChar
    where 
        lookupChar :: Char -> Maybe Int
        lookupChar c = lookup c lookupTable

-- Currently fails
test :: (Num n, Ord n) => [Maybe n] -> [Maybe n]
test seq = [ x * y | (x, y) <- zip seq $ tail seq, x < y ]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ test $ strToInts "ABC"
```

When I try running this, it returns the following error:

```
test.hs:13:16:
    Could not deduce (Num (Maybe n)) arising from a use of `*'
    from the context (Num n, Ord n)
      bound by the type signature for
                 test :: (Num n, Ord n) => [Maybe n] -> [Maybe n]
      at test.hs:12:9-48
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (Maybe n))
    In the expression: x * y
    In the expression: [x * y | (x, y) <- zip seq $ tail seq]
    In an equation for `test':
        test seq = [x * y | (x, y) <- zip seq $ tail seq]
```

I'm not 100% sure why this error is occurring, or what it exactly means, though I suspect it might be because I'm trying to multiply two `Maybe` monads together -- if I change the definition of `test` to the following, the program compiles and runs fine:

```
test :: (Num n, Ord n) => [Maybe n] -> [Maybe n]
test seq = [ x | (x, y) <- zip seq $ tail seq, x < y ]
```

I also tried changing the type declaration to the below, but that didn't work either.

```
test :: (Num n, Ord n) => [Maybe n] -> [Num (Maybe n)]
```

I'm not really sure how to go about fixing this error. I'm fairly new to Haskell, so it might just be something really simple that I'm missing, or that I've structured everything completely wrong, but this is stumping me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know what `Maybe` is actually made of?

Comment: You want to have a look at the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia), it will help you to understand the answers using `Applicative` a little bit more.

Comment: [`liftA2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2) and [`liftM2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2) are useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe does not have a num instance so you cannot multiply them together directly. You need to somehow apply the pure function to the values inside the context. This is exactly what applicative functors are for!

Applicative functors live in Control.Applicative:

```
import Control.Applicative
```

So you have this function and you want to apply it to 2 arguments in a context:

```
(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

You probably learned about fmap, it takes a function and applies it to a value in a context. `<$>` is an alias for fmap. When we fmap the pure function over the maybe value we get the following result:

```
(*) <$> Just 5 :: Num a => Maybe (a -> a)
```

So now we have maybe a function and we need to apply it to maybe a value, this is exactly what the applicative functor does. Its main operator is `<*>` which has the signature:

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

When we specialize it we get the function we need:

```
(<*>) :: Maybe (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

We apply it and the output is the number you expect.

```
(*) <$> Just 5 <*> Just 5 :: Num a => Maybe a
```

So to make your code compile you need to change your test function to use `<$>` and `<*>`, see if you can figure out how.

Comment: Right answer, but I think this is didactically unacceptable. Teach OP how to fish, rather than catching fish for them.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I changed my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Reite's answer is correct, and it's generally how I'd normally recommend handling it - however, it seems to me that you don't quite understand how to work with `Maybe` values; if so there is little sense looking at applicative functors right now.

The definition of `Maybe` is basically just

```
 data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

Which basically means exactly what it sounds like when you read it in plain english "A value of type `Maybe a` is either the value `Nothing` for that type, or a value of the form `Just a`".

Now you can use pattern matching to work with that, with the example of lists:

```
 maybeReverse :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
 maybeReverse Nothing = Nothing
 maybeReverse (Just xs) = Just $ reverse xs
```

Which basically means "If the value is `Nothing`, then there's nothing to reverse, so the result is `Nothing` again. If the value is `Just xs` then we can `reverse xs` and wrap it with `Just` again to turn it into a `Maybe [a]` value).

Of course writing functions like this for every single function we ever want to use with a `Maybe` value would be tedious; So higher order functions to the rescue! The observation here is that in `maybeReverse` we didn't do all that much with `reverse`, we just applied it to the contained value and wrapped the result of that in `Just`.

So we can write a function called `liftToMaybe` that does this for us:

```
 liftToMaybe :: (a->b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
 liftToMaybe f Nothing = Nothing
 liftToMaybe f (Just a) = Just $ f a
```

A further observation we can make is that because functions are values, we can also have `Maybe` values of functions. To do anything useful with those we could again unwrap them... or notice we're in the same situation as in the last paragraph, and immediately notice that we don't really care what function exactly is in that `Maybe` value and just write the abstraction directly:

```
 maybeApply :: Maybe (a->b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
 maybeApply Nothing _ = Nothing
 maybeApply _ Nothing = Nothing
 maybeApply (Just f) (Just a) = Just $ f a
```

Which, using our `liftToMaybe` function above, we can simplify a bit:

```
 maybeApply :: Maybe (a->b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
 maybeApply Nothing _ = Nothing
 maybeApply (Just f) x = liftToMaybe f x
```

The `<$>` and `<*>` operators in Reite's answer are basically just infix names for `liftToMaybe` (which is also known as `fmap`) and `maybeApply` respectively; They have the types

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a->b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a->b) -> f a -> f b
```

You don't really need to know what the `Functor` and `Applicative` things are right now (although you should look into them at some point; They're basically generalizations of the above `Maybe` functions for other kinds of "context") - basically, just replace `f` with `Maybe` and you'll see that these are basically the same functions we've talked about earlier.

Now, I leave applying this to your original problem of multiplication to you (although the other answers kinda spoil it).

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, the problem is that you are trying to multiply two `Maybe` values together, but `(*)` only works in instances of `Num`.

As it turn out, `Maybe` is an instance of the `Applicative` typeclass. This means that you can "lift" funcions that work with a type `a` to functions that work with a type `Maybe a`.

```
import Control.Applicative
```

Two functions provided by `Applicative` are:

`pure :: a -> f a` Puts a pure value in a "neutral context". For `Maybe`, this is `Just`.

`(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` Lets you apply a "function in a context" to two "values in a context".

So, suppose we have this pure computation:

```
(*) 2 3
```

Here are some analogous computations in a `Maybe` context:

```
Just (*) <*> Just 2 <*> Just 3
-- result is Just 6

pure (*) <*> pure 2 <*> pure 3
-- result is Just 6 -- equivalent to the above

pure (*) <*> pure 2 <*> Nothing
-- Nothing

Nothing <*> pure 2 <*> Just 3
-- Nothing

Nothing <*> Nothing <*> Nothing
-- Nothing
```

If the function or one of the argument is "missing", we return `Nothing`.

`(<*>)` is the explicit application operator when working with applicatives (instead of using a blank space, as when we work with pure values).

It's instructive to explore what `(<*>)` does with other instances of `Applicative`, like `[]`:

```
ghci> [succ,pred] <*> pure 3
[4,2]
ghci> [succ,pred] <*> [3]
[4,2]
ghci> pure succ <*> [2,5]
[3,6]
ghci> [succ] <*> [2,5]
[3,6]
ghci> [(+),(*)] <*> pure 2 <*> pure 3
[5,6]
ghci> [(+),(*)] <*> [2,1] <*> pure 3
[5,4,6,3]
ghci> [(+),(*)] <*> [2,1] <*> [3,7]
[5,9,4,8,6,14,3,7]
```