# How do you idiomatically add 1 to two Maybe Int and then multiply them together in haskell

Tags: haskell

Yesterday I read up some on the whole monad thing. I by no means grasp it, but it will not stop me from trying to use it. Some of the answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) really do push that monads is there to make things nicer, and more readable. 'Haskell has nice support for monads', does that mean that I can write nice code with for example maybe out of the box?

Or does it mean that I can write code for the maybe type which makes it easy to use.

I encountered the following problem when doing advent of code:

> Add 1 to the values in two Maybes and then multiply them together.

After reading [question on multiplying two maybes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268226/multiplying-the-value-within-two-maybe-monads) and also checking out [typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) I arrived at (after some serious head scratching):

```
let test = Just (*) <*> ((+1) <$> marker1Pos) <*> ((+1) <$> marker2Pos)
```

It works, but to me that looks less than ideal.

Can I do it with a do-block which I read about in the first link?

Comment: This looks cleaner to me: `getAp ((Ap marker1Pos + 1) * (Ap marker2Pos + 1))`. It uses a `newtype` that introduces numeric syntax for anything that's already a monad (and some stuff that isn't ;-).

Comment: Note that this doesn't require the `Monad` instance for `Maybe`, only its `Applicative` instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can do it with a `do`.

```
do  x <- marker1Pos
    y <- marker2Pos
    return ((x + 1) * (y + 1))
```

I would also tend to use `liftM2` or `liftA2` for the version you wrote, and I'd also tend to use `fmap` instead of `<$>` for sections.  You may or may not find this more appealing, but I offer it in case you do:

```
liftA2 (*) (fmap (+1) marker1Pos) (fmap (+1) marker2Pos)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can work with [**`on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) here:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)
import Data.Function(on)

f :: (Applicative f, Num a) => f a -> f a -> f a   
f = liftA2 (*) `on` fmap (1+)
```

Comment: Yyyeah... but this is a bit dubious. If we're going to factor out the "apply +1 to all", then we should probably right away do it on a _list_, i.e. `traverse product . map (fmap (+1))`.